# Flatten Tensor in Pytorch Convolutional Neural Network (size mismatch error)

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, pytorch, tensor

I made a reproducible example with random pixels. I'm trying to **flatten** the tensors for the dense layers after the **convolutional layers**. The problem is at the intersection of the convolutional layers and the dense layers. I don't know how to put the right number of neurons.

**tl;dr** I'm looking for the *manual* equivalent of `keras.layers.Flatten()` since it doesn't exist in `pytorch`.

```py
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

x = np.random.rand(1_00, 3, 100, 100)
y = np.random.randint(0, 2, 1_00)

if torch.cuda.is_available():
    x = torch.from_numpy(x.astype('float32')).cuda()
    y = torch.from_numpy(y.astype('float32')).cuda()

class ConvNet(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 32, 3)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 3)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(64, 128, 3)

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(128, 1024) # 128 is wrong here
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(1024, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv1(x)), (2, 2))
        x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv2(x)), (2, 2))
        x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv3(x)), (2, 2))
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = torch.sigmoid(self.fc2(x))
        return x

net = ConvNet()
net.cuda()
optimizer = optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=0.03)
loss_function = nn.BCELoss()

class Train:

    def __init__(self):
        self.len = x.shape[0]
        self.x_train = x
        self.y_train = y

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return x[index], y[index].unsqueeze(0)

    def __len__(self):
        return self.len

train = Train()
train_loader = DataLoader(dataset=train, batch_size=64, shuffle=True)

epochs = 1
train_losses = list()
for e in range(epochs):
    running_loss = 0
    for images, labels in train_loader:
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        log_ps = net(images)
        loss = loss_function(log_ps, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        running_loss += loss.item()
    print('It\'s working.')
```

Comment: If you want to fix the "128 is wrong here" comment, then you actually using PyTorch wrongly. In Keras, you statically define the network, that is why you can use the "flatten" without caring about the actual dimensions. 

If you insist, the proper way would be to query all the examples from your dataset, give them as an input to your CNNs, get the sizes of your outputs and then, if and only if all examples had same dimensions, you can calculate automatically the input features for your layers.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a function I made to automatically fit the right number of neurons while flattening a convolutional tensor:

```py
def flatten(w, k=3, s=1, p=0, m=True):
    """
    Returns the right size of the flattened tensor after
        convolutional transformation
    :param w: width of image
    :param k: kernel size
    :param s: stride
    :param p: padding
    :param m: max pooling (bool)
    :return: proper shape and params: use x * x * previous_out_channels

    Example:
    r = flatten(*flatten(*flatten(w=100, k=3, s=1, p=0, m=True)))[0]
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(r*r*128, 1024)
    """
    return int((np.floor((w - k + 2 * p) / s) + 1) / 2 if m else 1), k, s, p, m
```

In your case:

```py
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 32, 3)
    self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 3)
    self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(64, 128, 3)

    r = flatten(*flatten(*flatten(w=100, k=3, s=1, p=0, m=True)))[0]

    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(r*r*128, 1024)
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(1024, 1)

    def forward(self, x): ...
```

Answer (score 4):

You must be getting a size mismatch error, right?

That is because the output shape of the result after applying convolutions is `[B, 128, 10, 10]` and so the result of `.flatten` would be of shape `[B, 128*10*10]`. So you need to use a linear layer of input size `12800`. That should fix the problem.

So, just change

`self.fc1 = nn.Linear(128, 1024) # 128 is wrong here`

to

`self.fc1 = nn.Linear(12800, 1024)`

Usually, to get the idea of the right size, you can compute the shapes of output on paper, or just a `print(x.shape)` debug statement in the forward function at the right place will also do the job.

Comment: I made a function to calculate it automatically. Without a function, it doesn't really help to know that I need shape 12800 because next time it won't be. And I might have padding or something.

Comment: That's good! Your function does what I do on paper all the time.